# Counting from 0 to 99

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop

In C++, which of the following solutions is more robust and reliable to count from 0 to 99 and store each iteration in variables for tens and ones places? And how can either method be improved to make it as fast and non-resource intensive as possible?

```
typedef int (*IntFunction) (int* _SegmentList);

int display1SegmentPinNums[] = {...pin numbers...};
int display2SegmentPinNums[] = {...other pin numbers...};

// Then I have some functions that display a number to 7-segment displays. They each return an integer 1 and have a parameter of (int* _SegmentList), as per the type definition above

// An array of all the functions
IntFunction displayFunctions[10] = {display_0, display_1, display_2, display_3, display_4, display_5, display_6, display_7, display_8, display_9};

// Solution 1
for (int tens = 0; tens < 10; tens++)
{
    for (int ones = 0; ones < 10; ones++)
    {
        displayFunctions[tens](display1SegmentPinNums);
        displayFunctions[ones](display2SegmentPinNums);
    }
}

// Solution 2
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ones = (i % 10);
    tens = ((i - ones) / 10);

    displayFunctions[tens](display1SegmentPinNums);
    displayFunctions[ones](display2SegmentPinNums);
}
```

Edit:
I've included a somewhat simplified version of my full code. Hopefully it will help get an answer better. This is for an Arduino project BTW, with 7-segment displays and an attempt to make a stopwatch.

Comment: What is the problem?  How many times the tens increments and how many times the ones increments?  If so that is just math, no loop necessary.

Comment: *"And how can either method be improved to make it as fast and non-resource intensive as possible?"* Is your learning book from the 80s?

Comment: What is the larger problem you're trying to solve? I doubt this is the bottleneck in your code.

Comment: In solution 2 it is easier to see you are counting from 0 to 99. So I would prefer that, but it will depend on other requirements.

Comment: I'm dealing with around 30kb of RAM, so yes, resources are significant.

Comment: I agree with @Wimmel about the second solution, but please post the bigger picture issue!

Comment: FYI, in your second case, `tens = ((i - ones) / 10);` could just be `tens = i / 10;`; truncating integer division means the excess just gets dropped (that is, if `i == 19`, `i / 10 == 1`, you don't need to subtract `9` first). The former describes the changes in `tens` better (you could just make your loop variables `tens` and `ones` and save unnecessary names, while also ensuring that even without optimization, you don't needlessly reassign `tens` on each inner loop), but I wouldn't be the least surprised if optimizing compilers produced the same assembly for both.

Comment: A good compiler won't generate any code for either loop, since they don't do anything. (Which is pretty efficient.) What do you really want to do?

Comment: I'm building a timer using an Arduino.

Comment: Follow up to my last comment: As @AlanStokes notes, if you don't do anything with the values, an optimizing compiler will definitely compile them to the same thing (nothing); if you do something useful, it might still produce the same assembly from code analysis. You can usually ask your compiler to generate the assembly and check what differences might exist.

Comment: I'm using them as indexes to get elements from arrays.

Comment: Please post the real code.

Comment: More of the real code has been posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any decent optimizing compiler would come to the result that `tens` and `ones` contain `9` in the end, based on constant propagation, loop unrolling and dead code elimination.

Now depending on your real loop body, and not taking into account clever compiler optimizations, you can analyze your code, [counting type of operations](https://ideone.com/oUqupx):

- Solution 1:  11 initializations, 121 comparisons, 110 increments, 200 assignments
- Solution 2: 1 initialization, 101 comparisons, 100 increments, 200 assignments, 200 divisive operations ([modulo](http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2011/02/efficient-c-tip-13-use-the-modulus-operator-with-caution/) and division), 100 subtractions

Then it depends on CPU architecture and other factors:

- If hypothetically all operations would take one hypothetical CPU cycle, solution 1 would clearly win.
- But in reality it's much more complex, taking into account hardware optimization such as caching, branch prediction, and others, but also cost of modulo and division.  So the best way would certainly be to measure with some benchmarking code.

**Edit: about your code changes**

If the functions perform some side effects (displaying, etc), then of course, your loop body won't be optimized away.  The remaining comment I made remain true, because solution 1 and solution 2 both call the additional functions the same number of times with the same parameters.

Comment: Considering no compiler optimizations and a total 32kb of RAM for the computer in question, which would you advise?

Comment: @ZodiacZubeda intuitively I'd go for solution 1 (see the link behind "modulo" in my answer). Not all operators are equal in complexity and modulo and division are usually more complex, especially on low end cpu.  But this is intuition: only bechnmarking could give you a certain answer.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1 requires less computation, just addition, while solution 2 requires integer division and modulus operation in each iteration.

On the other hand, solution 1 requires an additional variable which might result in higher memory usage. But that depends on your hardware and on your compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

There two aspects in your question: Robustness and Reliability on one hand and speed and resource efficiency on the other. Depending on how you define these you may not be able to improve both side.

For robustness and reliability: no matter which solution you select the code you write in itself is fine as long as it works and goes through unit test is fine. But if you're not somehow measuring the robustness and reliability you won't know how good it is or how much you can improve it (and you will get different opinions from people who define these concepts differently).

For instance, if you decide that for you reliability is that the counting can not be interrupted or modified by another application running on your arduino machine. Then you should add countermeasure in your code to mitigate that risk, and test how your programme react to that type of situation. 
One way of counter measure could be for instance to get exclusive access to the resource until it finished counting. And as you can guess it will impair the speed & resource efficiency of your solution.

Therefore I would say it's rather difficult to answer your question in it's current state. I hope I still managed to give you some ideas to progress further.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments I'd go with the second solution since it is more concise and also states what it does more clearly (unlike the first one).

Also the second solution, as per your RAM requirements, is better, since it uses just 3 variables, not 4 as the first one.

But this fourth variable `j`, may only be several bytes (depending on platform), but usually 4.

Anyway, if you want to store all the "tens" and "ones", you'll need a list or a vector.

For a better, more specific answer, please post the bigger picture issue you're facing!

Comment: Not the downvoter, but: Let's be honest, on X86-64 there is no register spill for these 4 variables.